# Print sql output messages to a file in shell script

Tags: shell, sybase, isql

I need to run SQL scripts and wanted to capture that output to a log file.
I am trying to access Sybase using ISQL and below is the sample file, though only echo messages are getting printed in the log file.

Command that I am running on windows box is this:

```
./Test.sh > $JOBSROOT/Test/Scripts/logtest/test.log 2>&1

#!/bin/sh
#ident "%W%" 
#
echo "Trying to print"

ISQL_EOD="$ISQL -S $DB_SERVER -U $DB_DRMSUSER -P $DB_DRMSPASS -w999"

cd ${JOBSROOT}/Test/Scripts/logtest/
echo "Echo Prints"

$ISQL_EOD  << ADDE
set nocount on

select 'A HouseKeeper job'

set nocount off
ADDE
```

First time I am doing this hence could be wrong anywhere in this, please help me to understand it and find out the faulty line.

Comment: Unrelated but putting commands in strings is not a good idea. It doesn't work for complex commands. See [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for discussion about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your command is missing a `go`  In isql, commands are executed by issuing `go` on it's own line.

```
set nocount on

select 'EMEA VPE VOT Morning HouseKeeper job'

set nocount off

go
```

Comment: Yes. I noticed it just after putting this question here and then solved the problem that i was facing. However thanks for the help.